# jQuery glDatePicker plugin on input with array-noted name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of inputs in an array:

```
<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="date_picker" ... />
```

I am pulling in [gLDatepicker](http://code.gautamlad.com/glDatePicker/) in the rest of my form but it seems to break with the inclusion of the array notation.

Are there any ways around this or different jQuery date pickers that can be used instead?

Javascript to initiate:

```
$(".date_picker").glDatePicker(
    {
        allowOld: true,
        onChange: function(target, newDate){
            target.val
            (
            newDate.getDate()+"-"+(newDate.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+newDate.getFullYear()

        );
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: How does it break with the inclusion of array notation? Tried attaching via a class selector?

Comment: As soon as I remove the '[]' on the name the date selector operates normally. I run the date picker on window.onload

Comment: I used jQuery UI date picker and this is working as expected. The problem seems to be with gLdate picker. Will log an issue with them. Thanks for the soundboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of glDatePicker.

I am not sure what the issue was with glDatePicker in the version you used, but in the latest version (v2.0, released today) I don't see the issue.

I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cfRG2/

The new code looks like this:

```
$(window).ready(function()
{
    $(".date_picker").glDatePicker(
    {
        showAlways: true,
        selectableDateRange: [
            { from: new Date(2013, 0, 1),
                to: new Date(2015, 11, 31) },
        ],
        selectableYears: [2013, 2014, 2015],
        onClick: function(el, cell, date, data) {
            el.val
            (
                date.getDate()+"-"+(date.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+date.getFullYear()
            );
        }
    });
});​
```

Also, please note that some (many?) things have changed in version 2.0.  In regards to some of the options you have used, allowOld is no longer available and onChange has been changed to onClick.  You can work around this as shown in the jsfiddle example above.

You can read more about the changes and see complete examples here:
http://glad.github.com/glDatePicker

Good luck and let me know if you have any other questions!